# Sync directory tree algorithm assistance

Tags: python, algorithm, directory-structure

Could someone please take a look at my algorithm and see if they could fill in the areas with continuous dots??? I am making a Python program that looks at a remote directory tree and a local directory tree and syncs the two together, but im at a stumbling block:

```
(I have set folder checksums to be lists containing checksums of its children,
only files have md5 checksum strings instead of lists)

START

Go through whole local tree and compare each node to all remote nodes 
according to these rules:

    if the local file and a remote file have same md5 sum
    and one of those files is closer to todays date,
        if the one file is local,
            then delete remote file and upload local file.
        else
            then delete local file and download remote file.

    if the local folder and a remote folder have same checksum
    and one of those folders is closer to todays date,
        if the one folder is local,
            then ....
        else
            then ....

    else the local file/folder does not match any remote file/folder checksum,
        then ....

Go through whole remote tree and compare each node to all local nodes 
according to these rules:

    if the remote file/folder does not match any local file/folder checksum,
        then ....

DONE
```

Comment: That rather seems a decision you have to make. I don't think anyone can help you if you don't know what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand the parts you have already filled in. If the checksums match, why would you ever delete and redownload one of the files?

Comment: If the checksums are same i want to keep the one with the most recent dare modifed.

Comment: Im trying to sync for the mist updated version of files/folders

Comment: Similar to how dropbox or google drive clients work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I learned how GitHub commit trees worked and used them to solve my problem.

Comment: This doesn't look like an appropriate answer. Please extend it a bit.